# trying to extract contents.xml from openoffice spreadsheet ods file in c++ program

Tags: c++, openoffice-calc, ods

Anyone know of a way to unpack a ods file and read the contents.xml file?

In my program I'd like to be able to open my ods file, and extract the xml file for parsing.

Ive looked at minizip, but this is a ods file not a zip file. Is there any other way?

Any help is appreciated, thanks alot, Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the file extension it is still a zip archive, so minizip should work.

> The original OpenDocument format consists of an XML document that has
>    as its root element. OpenDocument files can also take the
>   format of a ZIP compressed archive containing a number of files and
>   directories; these can contain binary content and benefit from ZIP's
>   lossless compression to reduce file size.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument)

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. I just wish the documentation was a little better. I think I got it though, thanks.